Признак сжатия кривой до замыкания ее на саму себя
Решаю задачу численными методами.
Имеем замкнутую непересекающуюся внутри кривую сложной формы.
Исходные данные: таблица координат N точек: x,y
Расширяю и сжимаю (плавно) кривую в отдельных ее областях.
Иногда при втягивании во внутрь какойто области (локальном сжимании) возникает проблема - она пересекается с другой внутренней областю моей кривой.
Сейчас я задачу решаю в лоб -вычисляю расстояния между всеми точками (возможных комбинации N*(N-1)/2 ) Это отьедает колоссальное колво ресурсов.
Вопрос: нет ли математического решения узнать, пересекаются внутри области или нет?
Требуется ответ: Да/Нет

Математического способа отыскать самопересечение любой кривой нет. Если бы такой способ был, мы бы умели, в частности, искать корни любых уравнений, а этого нет. Есть технический способ со сложностью NlogN. Нужно только понимать, что технический способ (любой технический способ, в том числе и ваш из вопроса) не всегда будет обнаруживать пересечения. Но он работает достаточно хорошо если есть ограничения на производные в параметризации кривой.

Спасибо за ответ. Под термином  техническим способом, вы имеете ввиду решение численными методами? Подскажите , что за метод вычислений где колво итераций n*logn ?

В ответе к вашему вопросу упомянуты древовидные структуры, которые сработают за это время. Но чтобы точно ответить на ваш вопрос, надо понять как вы решаете задачу сейчас. Если в вашем решении всё в порядке кроме скорости, опишите его подробно в вопросе. Кто-нибудь (может и я) расскажет как ваше решение ускорить до NlogN.

Есть структуры данных, такие как R-tree и kd-tree, специально предназначенные для пространственного поиска. Они иерархически разбивают пространство на прямоугольники, и сложность поиска становится логарифмической.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Я нашел способ существенно сократить объем вычислений.
Так как кривая замкнута, то у каждой точки легко вычисляется признак: выпуклая точка или невыпуклая (простое вычисление по двум соседним точкам).
Выпуклая точка никогда не может явиться причиной замыкания на саму себя изнутри кривой.
Поэтому просто перебираем все невыпуклые точки.

Как насчет случая с кривой в форме "резинки для волос наложенной на себя 3-4 раза" - все точки выпуклые, самопересечений 2-3 штуки.
